# When we should use liquibase?

Tags: database, liquibase

I have searched for this answer on many websites,and I am getting almost same answer everywhere.

- Liquibase helps ensure software releases are always delivered with
  the matching state of the database so your features are deployed
  quickly and confidently.
- We can specify changes once and test them on different databases.
- We could pick and choose the changes to be applied in different environments(dev, staging, QA) if we have such a requirement.

This can be done by using Jpa too (using different properties file for staging, dev, production). Then when we should use liquibase, and when it is required?

Comment: The competitor to [*Liquibase*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) is [*Flyway*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)), not [*Jakarta Persistence*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence) (formerly JPA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase & JPA are very different & have completely separate use cases.

Liquibase is a library for tracking, managing, and applying database schema changes automatically. Liquibase helps track all of your database schema changes in your own files (sql, xml, yml, json). You can think of liquibase as a versioning-type tool for database scripts.

Say somebody inserts new data into a table but, only did it for one environment when it should have been done for all of them. Now an even worse case scenario is that person leaves their company & now no one knows they are missing data. This is a perfect example of how you lose consistency overtime due to careless errors when managing multiple databases or multiple schemas. With liquibase they wouldn't have to worry because that database change is now properly saved & will execute for each environment that that code is deployed to. Essentially, your liquibase scripts are now somewhat part of your project's code (depending on where they live of course).

On the other hand, JPA can validate your existing codebase against your database but, it won't make the necessary DB changes for you (unless you specify something like create-drop which I don't recommend for most use cases). Whenever you use any of their annotations such as `@Entity`, `@Table`, `@Id`, `@Blob`, etc., none of those changes are automatically applied to your database. JPA is great for modeling how your tables, relationships, & constraints should look in your database. However, it is usually up to you to execute the necessary SQL (or other query language) for such changes. That's where liquibase can conveniently handle it for you.

Comment: So If I am using liquibase, with spring boot then if I want to insert record to database then It is appropriate to use liquibase changeset for inserting data to database instead of apis ? I am asking this because  usually whenever we are making an spring boot application we usually integrates apis for performing Operations.

Comment: @KhushaliJiyani No you shouldn't use liquibase for tracking insertion from API's in my opinion. My above example, was for manually inserted data that didn't come from any process or app. So generally speaking, any schema changes you would make can be supported by liquibase. If you want to track creation of tables, alter existing tables, alter constraints, grant privileges, etc. Also, sometimes in a prod setting your options for making DB changes might be limited but, because liquibase is in sync with project code it will now get started with your app at runtime (or whenever you specify)